# Display Image in android Imageview using Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmapimage

I have an image being sent to me through a JSON string. I want to convert that string into an image in my android app and then display that image in my imageview.I have a problem, I am using Asynctask and this is my code in the doInBackground method:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args){

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        if(json!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                try{
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String displayImageFromUrl = c.getString(imageUrl);
                    String clearUrl = displayImageFromUrl.substring(displayImageFromUrl.indexOf(",")+1);
                    byte[] decodingString = Base64.decode(clearUrl, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodingString, 0 , decodingString.length);

                    String showCreatedDate = c.getString(createdDate);
                    String showArticleTitle = c.getString(articleTitle);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(createdDate, showCreatedDate);
                    map.put(articleTitle, showArticleTitle);

                    jsonlist.add(map);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{

        }
        return null;
    }
```

and this is my code in the onPostExecute() method:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success){
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        Log.d("image please",bitmap.toString());
        ImageView showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageShow);
        showImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.activity_news,
                new String[] {createdDate, articleTitle},
                new int[] { R.id.createDate, R.id.articleTitle});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();
    }
```

Unfortunately nothings shows up in my logcat. Can you help me?
What do I miss??

Comment: your question isn't clear.. Do you want to display image from url ?

Comment: yes and that is base64 encoding,

Comment: There are a few things with this code. Firstly you have a bitmap variable somewhere, but iterating over the json array would overwrite the bitmap object every time. Secondly it looks like you always return null from the `doInBackground` method, I would suggest passing the jsonlist variable instead. Thirdly, could you post a sample response so that we can see if you do anything wrong with the parsing.

Comment: you mean in my logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pseudocode. If you use it in project it should be working.

```
//my image (android logo)
private String base64 = "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";

//somewhere in code
imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);//layout params are wrap and wrap

//weak reference is for safe using imageView when app i.e will exit and task will still be running
weakReferenceImageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        byte[] encode = Base64.decode(base64.getBytes(), 0);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encode, 0, encode.length);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        if (bitmap != null) {                                      
            if (weakReferenceImageView != null) {                  
                ImageView weak = weakReferenceImageView.get();
                if (weak != null) {                           
                    weak.setImageBitmap(bitmap);              
                }                                                  
            }                                                      
        }                                                          

    }
}.execute();
```

If decoding is wrong, returned bitmap will be null.
Please try with my image (it is very small) if it works. If it works it means something is wrong with your based64 image.

---

Fixed example, added weakReference as a good sample of coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

Use the library found on the url. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/
ImageLoader.java, FileCache.java, and Utils.java

Comment: but im using base64 encoding

Comment: Why do you need to be a base64? And also, your process is to load an image to imageview when aysnctask finished. right? I think it is not possible.

Comment: it is possible, if you say it is impossible it is good to point sources explaining your opinion..

Comment: This is answers the wrong question. The author clearly states that she gets the image data in the json string, so there is no url to fetch the image from.

Comment: I think author has an error on the question. We cannot display an image on the JSON string.

Comment: Hum... read the comments on the question and I think you might be correct on the url part. It is technically possible to include binary data in the json, though it is actually less efficient then including a url and downloading the image in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Couldn't be easier than this.